# How to exclude multiple labels from Prometheus Query?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, telemetry

I want to exclude mulitple app groups from my query... Not sure how to go about it.. My thoughts are like this

```
count(master_build_state{app_group~! "oss-data-repair", "pts-plan-tech-solution", kubernets_namespace = "etc"} ==0)
```

I do not want to include those two app_groups, but am not sure how to implement in PromQL. You would thing to add () or [], but it throws errors. Let me know if anyone can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
count(master_build_state{app_group !~ "(oss-data-repair|pts-plan-tech-solution)", kubernets_namespace="etc"} ==0)
```

Comment: `~!` should be `!~`

Answer (score 9):

you can use the `!=` [comparison binary operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) to do that. Just write it twice on your promQL.

```
count(
  master_build_state{
    app_group!="oss-data-repair", 
    app_group!="pts-plan-tech-solution",
    kubernets_namespace="etc"} 
== 0)
```